filter if sum of rows larger than value
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1,2,3,4), z = c("A","B","A","B"))

I'm trying to use dplyr's filter function to filter to rows whose sum is greater than 4.
I tried:
df %>% filter_at(vars(c(x,y)), any_vars(rowSums(.) > 4))

Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `rowSums(x) > 4 | rowSums(y) > 4`.
Caused by error in `rowSums()`:
! 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Desired output:
  x y z
  3 3 A
  4 4 B


Maybe df %>% filter(rowSums(across(-z)) > 4)

Use pick() inside rowSums():
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(pick(x:y)) > 4)
#   x y z
# 1 3 3 A
# 2 4 4 B

(Also note that scoped verbs like filter_at() have been superseded by across() and pick().)

I couldn't figure out how to do it with rowSums, mainly because it requires two inputs and when you use filter_if or if_any() you are passing through a column as list one by one
However the below will work
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(
        row_total=sum(c_across(x:y))
    ) |>
    filter(row_total>5) |> 
    select(-row_total)

As suggested by @zephryl in the comments, you can further reduce the above by simply putting sum(c_across(x:y))>5 directly in filter
df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    filter(sum(c_across(x:y))>5)

This is more of a direct replacement for rowSums() in the OP's question.

in c_across() you can use any tidyselect verbs eg. where(is.numeric) would work as well

You could simplify this by dropping the mutate() and select() steps and just using filter(sum(c_across(x:y)) > 5).

oh that is a good one -- because the columns are grouped by rowwise -- is that right?

Not quite sure what you mean, but it works because you can use any expression in filter(), you don’t have to compute a named column first.
